# sed regex to get filename without extension with ()

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a string `GameOfThronesS01E05.mkv`. I want `GameOfThronesS01E05` using `sed` with regex.

I tried

```
echo GameOfThronesS01E05.mkv | sed 's/\(.+\)\.mkv$/\1/'
```

and it didn't work

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `basename GameOfThronesS01E05.mkv .mkv`?

Comment: `+` is literal in BRE - you need `\+` if you want it to be treated as a quantifier. But there are much simpler ways to remove extensions.

Comment: `sed -r 's/(.+)\.mkv$/\1/'`

Comment: @JJoao `sed: illegal option -- r` on Mac

Comment: Yeah there are many ways to do that.I just want to know whats wrong with my expression.

Comment: @steeldriver `\+` didn't work

Comment: In that case your implementation of sed may not support it - the POSIX BRE equivalent would be `\{1,\}` (one or more) iirc

Comment: @don_crissti `$ echo filename.mkv | sed -E 's/\(.\+\)\.mkv$/\1/'`
`sed: 1: "s/\(.\+\)\.mkv$/\1/": \1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: neckTwi - it doesn't work because you have escaped those chars; run `sed -E 's/(.+)\.mkv$/\1/'` though there are better ways to do this, even with `sed`...

Comment: `.+` can always be replaced by `..*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a system that has GNU utilities, you can always use `basename` to strip the extension:

```
$ basename -s ".mkv" GameOfThronesS01E05.mkv                                                          
GameOfThronesS01E05
```

Otherwise, python is always a good choice,too:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print sys.argv[1][:-4]' GameOfThronesS01E05.mkv                               
GameOfThronesS01E05
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more simpler solution:

```
echo GameOfThronesS01E05.mkv | sed -n 's/.mkv//p'
```

Comment: I just want to know whats wrong with my expression.

Comment: why do you need `-n` and `p` ? and as a general rule, the dot has to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @don_crissti. here is my MKV to MP4 converter

```
$vi /usr/local/bin/MKVtoMP4
for entry in *
do
        if [[ $entry =~ .+\.mkv$ ]]; then
                FILENAME=`echo $entry | sed -E 's/(.+)\.mkv$/\1/'`
                ffmpeg -i "$entry" -codec copy "${FILENAME}.mp4"
        fi
done
chmod ug+x /usr/local/bin/MKVtoMP4
```

Comment: 1. This does not answer your question. 2. You can use `./*.mkv` instead of `*` - that way you can get rid of that `if` condition 3. You can also get rid of that `FILENAME` assignment and simply run `for entry in ./*.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$entry" -codec copy "${entry%.*}.mp4"; done` - so one line of code instead of seven...

Comment: thats embarrassing. lost all the triumph